# const QList<int> warnings = QList<int>() << 0; segfaults with gcc 4.7.2

Tags: c++, qt, gcc4.7

So the code mentioned on the topic line causes segmentation fault with Qt 4.8.3 & gcc 4.7.2

This is at outside of any classes/structs at .cpp-file and works with gcc 4.4

```
const QList<int> warnings = QList<int>() << 0 << 3 << 7;
```

Traces gives these two hints:

```
__do_global_ctors()
__static_initialization_and_destruction_0
```

So it seems that "warning" is not yet available when its inserting latter list into it.

Works with 4.7.2 if i change it into this:

```
global scope: QList< int> warnings;
```

This is inisde some function:

```
warnings = QList<int>() << 0 << 3;
```

I'm wondering why this happens?

**Edit:**

I guess i clipped a bit too much stuff out from my question originally, but warnings is supposed to be const at file scope (.cpp-file) for holding bunch enums.

Comment: This may seem very trivial. Is the expression solved as `const QList<int> warnings = (QList<int>() << 0 << 3 << 7);`, right?

Comment: Moreover, what about `const QList<int> warnings = QList<int> << 0 << 3 << 7;`? (No parentheses to call constructor.)

Comment: That would be pretty much the same as writing `int i = int << 1;` Won't compile.

Comment: indeed I am still wondering [how can one achieve that](http://ideone.com/Qh2RXP) using temporary objects..

Comment: By ending the class definition with a colon? http://ideone.com/dVFBWf :)

Comment: @jrok, LoL I was going crazy.... :)... Btw, the definition `a operator<< (a t, const int j) { t.i = j; return t; };` can't use `a&`, which you need to iterate the `<<`..right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "iterate", but `operator<<` overload should return (and take) a reference, so you call it on the same instance when chaining.

Comment: @jrok, that is right; although that won't work in the current ideone example because you cannot reference temp objects [consider this](http://ideone.com/uN1duJ)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My psychic debugging powers tell me that the line in question exists at global/file scope, not at class/function scope. Thus your line may be called at any point during static initialization. With your old gcc it just so happened that QT was initialized *before* your line was called. With the new gcc it reordered (perfectly legal) the static init to call your function first, before QT was ready to create objects and insert into them.

The solution is to hold off on creating that `QList` until after `main` starts. Using pointers or static local objects are two common implementations.

Comment: I think you are right. With those two (do_global_ctors..) functions at the stack its doing the static initialization for global/file scope.Too bad that the code base i inherited is full of const qlist's like that one.