# const object initialization as `const Vect const_vect = Vect() << 1 << 2;`

Tags: c++, initialization, constants

Some hours ago I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13270738/1714661) in which the user initialized a `const` object as

```
const QList warnings = QList() << 0 << 3 << 7;
```

Indeed, this expression somehow hurt me because going against the concepts I have of `const` and of overloading `operator<<`.

I tried to define an `operator<<` possibly allowing for the mentioned expression and here is what I got:

```
typedef vector<int> Vect; 
Vect operator<<(Vect v, const int i){ //ByVal v, This way it works, but at which cost? 
    v.push_back(i);                   //v is copied at every call!
    return v;
};      

//Here is where I build the object
const Vect const_vect = Vect() << 1 << 2;  
//it works fine but I see massive overhead due to copies..@_@

//Just for testing
int main() {
    for(auto e = const_vect.begin(); e!=const_vect.end() ; ++e){ 
       cout << *e << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The previous code (which is also [here](http://ideone.com/xFOwuu)) works fine.

The following, on the other hand, is the expression I would have expected from the definition of `operator<<`:

```
 Vect& operator<<(Vect& v, const int i){  //ByRef v<-this I would have expected;                                                
    v.push_back(i);                        //however it can't work because receives and 
    return v;                              //returns reference to temporary object.
 };
```

---

My question is: *what am I missing?* is the `operator<<` defined in `QList` differently implemented from mine, in particular, can it receive and return `ByRef`?

Secondly, is perhaps the aforementioned a standard procedure to initialize *complex* `const` objects?

Thirdly (maybe inconvenient), how would such an expression handled by the compiler? what is done at compile-time and what at run-time?

Comment: What you're missing is that operator<< overloads for QList are *member functions*, not free functions. The temporary in initializer doesn't bind to any reference, the operator is being called on it instead.

Comment: @CharlesBailey, you can't pass temporary objects by reference. The code, in fact, doesn't compile.

Comment: @jrok. Nice. That's good, thanks,  I saw the [reference](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qlist.html#operator-lt-lt). Therein `operator<<` returns byref a temporary object, which still [can't work](http://ideone.com/KvBkpg).

Comment: That's a different issue you've got there in the linked code - it's trying to convert a const ref to non-const ref. [This, however, works just fine](http://ideone.com/3dpQw6).